# JTA Transaction Timeout Troubleshooting

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, jta

Setup:

- Oracle 12 DB
- JBoss EAP7
- Webservice running on JBoss, inserts into DB
- Batchprogramm calling the webservice from multiple threads about 130.000 times in the span of an hour

The problem:

> 2018-04-26 18:20:44,675 +0200 [WARN ] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffffac110923:-4c44ed1d:5ac9329e:6866ea in state  RUN
>
> 2018-04-26 18:20:44,675 +0200 [WARN ] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffffac110923:-4c44ed1d:5ac9329e:6866ea invoked while multiple threads active within it.
>
> 2018-04-26 18:20:44,679 +0200 [WARN ] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012381: Action id 0:ffffac110923:-4c44ed1d:5ac9329e:6866ea completed with multiple threads - thread default task-48 was in progress with xxx.BaseEntity.getNextValue(BaseEntity.java:28)

This happens routinely in the production environment under heavy load, not when processing fewer records and not in an identical test environment with the exact same load.

The last line shows that this transaction timeout (300s) occurs while fetching the next value from a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "XXX_S"  MINVALUE xxx MAXVALUE xxx INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH xxx CACHE 2 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION ;
```

I know Oracle needs to lock/unlock the sequence in order to keep it consistent, so my parallel webservice calls must somehow run into a deadlock or massive contention, producing the timeout.

How do I find the root of this problem? Which parameters can I try to manipulate?

Comment: Status: sad. Issue: unresolved. Will update if I ever find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is now resolved, though very unsatisfyingly. We removed parallelism.